# Replace Into causing MySQL syntax error at "WHERE"

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to use Replace Into to create a usercount script in php however at the moment it seems to be throwing a MySQL Error which I Cannot decipher.

```
$db->query("REPLACE INTO onlinenow (`time`,`ip`) VALUES ('$timestamp','$ip') WHERE ip = '$ip' ");
```

to me looks correct, however causes the error

> MySQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
> that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
> use near 'WHERE ip = 'REDACTED'' at line 1

Does anybody have any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

`REPLACE INTO` doesn't have a `WHERE` clause. Valid syntax options are shown in the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html .

**Long answer:**

It doesn't have one because it doesn't need one - the same documentation says:

> if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a
> PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new
> row is inserted

This will happen automatically. In your case I'm assuming it's going to be the IP column which should have the `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` constraint on it.

So you can simply remove the WHERE clause from your query and the rest should work.

---

P.S. I would strongly urge you to build your queries in PHP securely using parameterised queries and prepared statements, instead of using simple string concatenation as you're doing now. This is will protect you from SQL Injection attacks and also greatly reduce the risk of other unexpected syntax errors (e.g. due to quote marks in the input values and similar issues).